# Issues Triggering Dataflow Job from Cloud Function: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions_framework'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am doing a simple Cloud Function based on a file upload into GCS, this would trigger a Dataflow job. For the sake of simplicity, my current pipeline simply reads the file from GCS and then writes it to another bucket. While this Dataflow job works well without Cloud Function, Cloud Function does something else. It logs the file details correctly, it triggers a Dataflow job, but then Dataflow fails with a "module not found" error. Hence, while the function executes and triggers the job properly, the Dataflow job does not come through. Here is the code that I have:

```
 def hello_gcs(event, context):
     import apache_beam as beam
     from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
     input_file = f"gs://{event['bucket']}/{event['name']}"
     output_path = 'gs://<gcs_output_path>'
     dataflow_options = ['--project=<project_name>', '--runner=DataflowRunner','--region=<region>','--temp_location=gs://<temp_location>']
     options = PipelineOptions(dataflow_options, save_main_session = True)


     print('Event ID: {}'.format(context.event_id))
     print('Event type: {}'.format(context.event_type))
     print('Bucket: {}'.format(event['bucket']))
     print('File: {}'.format(event['name']))
     print('Metageneration: {}'.format(event['metageneration']))
     print('Created: {}'.format(event['timeCreated']))
     print('Updated: {}'.format(event['updated']))

     p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

     print_files = (p | beam.io.ReadFromText(input_file) | beam.io.WriteToText(output_path, file_name_suffix='.txt'))

     result = p.run()
```

I also have a "requirements.txt" file added in the same directory as my function for the following two dependencies:

```
 apache-beam[gcp]==2.39.0
 functions-framework==3.*
```

I have seen in multiple comments that making a Dataflow template bypasses this issue, but I am wondering if anyone may have an idea why this error is being thrown, if it can be circumvented through modification of the current setup, and if not, how to alternately create a template such that this input file can be fed as a parameter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a limitation of the `save_main_session` approach to staging dependencies. The `functions-framework` is not needed for Beam or Dataflow, but is just something that is loaded into the interpreter during the execution of your Cloud Function.

I suggest disabling the `save_main_session` option and/or using the `--requirements_file` or `--setup_file` options to provide a specification of the dependencies your pipeline will need at runtime.

Detailed documentation for dependency management is at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

Comment: Yes. I got it to work properly by just removing save_main_session. I know with this code it was a simple modification, but more involved code obviously necessitates having the --requirements_file or --setup_file. Would you think it's wise to just make the pipeline a separate function altogether? That way it can have all the dependencies without getting into the global scope? Thank you, once again, for your help!

Comment: I think your code is fine and you don't have to change it. But as a general thing I recommend building the whole pipeline as a PTransform (with `expand` method and everything). And then your main code just does the setup and applies the one PTransform.